# PHP getting count for values that falls within expected ranges

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, range

I have a list containing a bunch of values from 1-400. I am trying to divide the data into ranges like [1-50], [51-100], .. , [351-400] and get the count for the values that falls within the range given . I basically have the code working. So, my question would be is there a better way to do this or what would be a good practise for this?

```
$temp = array(); //temp array to store the values from mysql
$final_array = array //final array to store the counts from the range initialized to 0 
    (
            "0" => 0,
            "1-50" => 0,
            "51-100" => 0,
            "101-150" => 0,
            "151-200" => 0,
            "201-250" => 0,
            "251-300" => 0,
            "301-350" => 0,
            "351-400" => 0
    );

$sql = "SELECT count(*) AS total FROM user GROUP BY user_id";

$statement = $DB_->link->prepare ( $sql );
$statement->execute ();

    if ($result = $statement->get_result ())
    {
        while ( $row = $result ->fetch_assoc() )
        {
            $temp [] = $row;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    foreach ($temp as $child)
    {
        if( $child['total'] >= 351 && $child['total'] <= 400)
        {
            $final['351-400']++;            
        }
        elseif( $child['total'] >= 301 && $child['total'] <= 350)
        {
            $final['301-350']++;            
        }
        ...
        elseif( $child['total'] >= 1 && $child['total'] <= 50)
        {
            $final['1-50']++;           
        }
    }
```

Desired results

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => 0 
    [1-50] => 1 
    [51-100] => 0 
    [101-150] => 0 
    [151-200] => 1 
    [201-250] => 0 
    [251-300] => 4 
    [301-350] => 5 
    [351-400] => 18 
)
```

Comment: Do all the ranges span up over integer multiples of 50? If so, you could easily get rid of that huge `if...elseif` construct at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would iterate over the keys of `final_array`, exploding them using `-` as the delimiter. While this method is slower than what you have, as it's iterating over `final_array` for each row returned from the database, it is much more maintainable, as it seamlessly handles keys for exact matches (only 1 number), and arbitrary ranges. Adding more buckets simply requires editing the `final_array` array, rather than changing a bunch of lines of code.

```
foreach ($temp as $child) {
    foreach($final_array as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, '-') === false) {
            if ($child['total'] == intval($key)) {
                $final_array[$key]++;
            }
        } else {
            list($min, $max) = explode('-', $key);
            if ($child['total'] >= intval($min) && $child['total'] <= intval($max)) {
                $final_array[$key]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would also forgo the use of the `$temp` array, simply processing the results as they are returned:

```
if ($result = $statement->get_result ())
{
    while ( $child = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        foreach($final_array as $key => $value) {
            if (strpos($key, '-') === false) {
                if ($child['total'] == intval($key)) {
                    $final_array[$key]++;
                }
            } else {
                list($min, $max) = explode('-', $key);
                if ($child['total'] >= intval($min) && $child['total'] <= intval($max)) {
                    $final_array[$key]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

The most efficient system would load all the results in an array, pass that array through [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), and then aggregate those.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way which you used & for single key count we use PHP function [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)